# Running Transmission as Root

Tags: command-line, transmission

How can I run Transmission as `root`?

I have tried

```
sudo transmission
```

with no joy.

qBittorrent works, but I have to download it.

Comment: You meant the GUI version of `transmission`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The appropriate name of the graphical binary is `transmission-gtk` and as it a graphical application to run it as `root` using `sudo` use:

```
gksudo transmission-gtk
```

To interactively work in the termianl again, put it in background:

```
gksudo transmission-gtk &
```

Answer (score 2):

As [heemayl](https://askubuntu.com/users/216503/heemayl) stated in his answer, you can start it from terminal that way, but if you don't want to start terminal every time, you can modify the command to start transmission by adding `gksu` in the beginning of the command.  See image below.

[image]

Or modify the .Desktop file

[image]